# Using data.table for multiple aggregation steps

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table

I am trying to do multiple aggregation steps using `data.table`. First I want to find the median value at each concentration for a specific type of sample by plate, then I want to find the maximum of the medians for each plate.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(plate = rep(paste0("plate",1:3),each=11),
                 type = rep(c(rep(1,9),2,2),3),
                 value = sample(1:25,33,replace=TRUE),
                 conc = rep(c(rep(1:3,each=3),4,4),3)
                 )
```

I got the following to work:

```
DT[,med := median(value[type==1]),by=list(plate,conc)]
DT[,max := max(med,na.rm=TRUE),by=plate]
```

Is it possible to do a multiple step aggregation without adding the intermediate `med` column?

Comment: What's wrong with two subsequent commands? Will you eventually try to condense your entire script into a single line?! :-)

Comment: @SimonO101 I agree. I am just trying to understand how the `data.table` package works and I knew there would be a way to condense it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could e.g. do the following:

```
DT[, max := max(.SD[, median(value[type == 1]), by = conc]$V1, na.rm = T),
     by = plate]
```

but I'm pretty sure your two line way is much faster.

Comment: Now that's interesting. I expected the inner call to the data.table would have needed plate in the by assignment. I also would not have thought to use .SD, rather than referencing DT again - which obviously did not work (even when I added plate to the by assignment).